# Update user info in DotNetNuke database

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've created a custom module that users can update their first name, last name and password information from. I've found out how to update the password but whatever i try to do with the names doesn't work. I've tried using both the usercontroller and profilecontoller classes and while they dont throw any errors the data in the database doesn't seem to be getting updated.

I've searched around for a long time but I can't seem to find anything on this, even though I imagine it probably is actually quite simple.

Can someone help me with this?

Also at the same time do I need to update the display name property or will it do that automatically?

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to find the answer to this, I don't know what it was that I was doing wrong but I tried the code below and it now updates with no problem:

```
userInfo.Profile.FirstName = firstName;
userInfo.Profile.LastName = Surname;
userInfo.FirstName = firstName;
userInfo.LastName = Surname;
userInfo.DisplayName = firstName + " " + Surname;
ProfileController.UpdateUserProfile(userInfo);

int portalId = userInfo.PortalID;

UserController.UpdateUser(portalId, userInfo);
```

It looks like you might need to update the user details and the user profile details in order to get the change working. Hope this is helpful for others